# iOS app crashes without any exception after tapping IBOutlet with assigned IBAction (UIButton)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

My task is to create custom `UIAlertView` with multiline text input field and everything works pretty much well up to the point where I need to do some actions if dismiss button was tapped. As example I'm using: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/custom-alert-views.html

I have created very simple popup for testing purpose. Basically it's `UIViewController` xib with single button in it. The main class is demonstrated below:

```
#import "testViewController.h"

@interface testViewController ()

@end

@implementation testViewController

- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"testViewController" bundle:nil];

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)showInView:(UIView *)view
{
    [view addSubview:[self view]];
    [[self view] setFrame: [view bounds]];
    [[self view] setCenter:[view center]];
}

- (IBAction)onTap:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"All OK");
}

@end
```

then in root `UIViewController` I'm calling my custom alert:

```
- (IBAction)showAlert:(id)sender
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        testViewController *alert = [[testViewController alloc] init];
        [alert showInView:[self view]];
    });
}
```

So far I have tried Main thread or global queue or even synchronous dispatch, but everything ends up with break on:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); <-- Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xa000000c)
    }
}
```

tried to add observer for the button but still no go..

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: use exception break point to track the error

Comment: Hi, thanks mahi vamsi for your input. I just found that the problem is that my testViewController is released by ARC before I tap the dismiss button. Now the question is how to retain my testViewController using ARC? Ideally I would like to make it the same way as native UIAlertView when I don't have to store variable (fire and forget)?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using exception break point but the app always stops at the point described in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what happing is "if you want to add one viewcontroller view to other viewcontroller's view then after adding of views you should convey to the compiler that second view controller is going to be child to the first"

i.e pre intimation of parent to child relationship has to be done.

now just modify your showAlert method with the following . it is working  100%.

```
- (IBAction)showAlert:(id)sender {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        testViewController *alert = [[testViewController alloc] init];
        [alert showInView:[self view]];

        [self addChildViewController:alert];
        [alert didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    });
}
```

Comment: if you satisfy with my answer please click the right mark or vote me :)))

Answer (score 0):

Check if your UIButton is assigned multiple IBoutlets or multiple IBActions. This a common issue which happens without our notice sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my testViewController was released by ARC before I tap the button